# If $a,z \in \mathbb{R}$ who have property $z+a=a$ then $z=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

I have two proof for this theorem, please tell me which one is more correct. Also let me know if something goes wrong, thanks.

1. First proof

$\begin{align}
z&=z+0 \quad \text{additional identity}\\
&=z+(a+(-a)) \quad \text{additional inverse}\\
&=(z+a)+(-a) \quad \text{additional associative}\\
&=a+(-a) \quad \text{known }z+a=a\\
&=0\quad \text{additional inverse}
\end{align}$

2. Second proof

$\begin{align}
z+a&=a \\
(z+a)+(-a)&=a+(-a) \\
z+(a+(-a))&=0 \quad \text{additional associative and identity}\\
z+0&=0 \quad \text{additional inverse}\\
z&=0\quad \text{additional identity}
\end{align}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as "more correct" when talking about proofs. A proof can only be one of two things: correct or incorrect. A half correct proof is incorrect. A 99.999999% correct proof is incorrect.

Both your proofs are correct, and there is nothing better or worse about either of them. Personally, I think the second is a little easier to understand, but that might not be true for everyone.